# How to filter out empty elements in arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have a line of code that iterates over an array and rejects any empty elements:

```
survey.reject!(&:empty?).map! { |feedback| %(_"#{feedback}"_) }
```

If the entire array is empty, this works as expected.  If one of the elements in the array is not empty I get an error `map!` doesn't exist.

This, however, has no problems:

```
survey.map! { |feedback| %(_"#{feedback}_") }
```

The `reject` function works when the entire array is empty, and `map!` version works when the array isn't empty.  How can I best consolidate these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got to be careful when using in-place modifiers. As [the documentation for `reject!` says](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-reject-21):

> Deletes every element of `self` for which the block evaluates to *true*, if no changes were made returns `nil`.

Due to that feature, you can't chain these like you can the versions that reliably make copies.

What you can do is do it on two lines:

```
survey.reject!(&:empty?)
survey.map! { |feedback| %(_"#{feedback}"_) }
```

Or you can chain-reassign:

```
survey = survey.reject(&:empty?).map { |feedback| %(_"#{feedback}"_) }
```

Comment: I'd much rather work on chained-reassigning code. I think I've used `reject!` and `map!` only a handful of times, but I've used `reject` and `map` more times than I can count.

Comment: @theTinMan Totally agreed, though my ratio is more like 1 in 50 times for the in-place versions versus their copy yielding counterparts.

Comment: I have to confess I still drag around a Perl-based mentality of chaining array and hash processing. Old dogs and all that.

Answer (score 3):

[`Array#reject!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-reject-21) returns `nil` if it didn't change anything. `nil` doesn't have a `map!` method, so you get a `NoMethodError`.

Why are you chaining side-effecting methods anyway? The purpose of a side-effecting method is its side-effect, not its return value. You can just do

```
survey.reject!(&:empty?)
survey.map! { |feedback| %(_"#{feedback}"_) }
```

Or, better yet: don't use side-effects. They're evil.

```
survey = survey.reject(&:empty?).map { |feedback| %(_"#{feedback}"_) }
```

Note, however, that this does *not* do the same thing as the above: the above mutates the single object that is *referenced* by `survey`. This mutates the reference `survey` itself and makes it point to a *different* object.

This is cleaner overall, but if there is other code in your system that depends on mutable shared state and side-effects, it will have to be changed, too.

Comment: Definitely don't use side-effects. Their use might be clear to the person writing the code initially, but their effect very likely won't be obvious to the person maintaining the code. Even well documented code that isn't obvious can be a problem late at night or when in a rush to fix a production-down problem.